# Change the leading and title according to Appbar height

Tags: flutter, dart

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: 
    PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(120),// change appbar size
    
      child:AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255,254,202,8),
        leading:RawMaterialButton( 
          constraints: BoxConstraints(),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0), 
          child: Image.asset("assets/img/home.png",height:110), // set height as 110
        ),

        title:Text("mytitle");
```

I changed appbar height by `preferredSize`

and set leading Image height as `100`

AppBar height is changed but leading icon size is not changed.

And text too.

How can I change leading and text size according to appbar size??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to change the `leading` size in the `AppBar`, but a workaround is to use a `Row` containing the image and the title and set this row as the `flexibleSpace` of the `AppBar`:

```
AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 254, 202, 8),
              flexibleSpace: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  RawMaterialButton(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      "assets/img/home.png",
                      height: 110,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("mytitle"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```